# Modifying data in dataset

Tags: data

I have a set of data

```
DataUfunction = {{0.05`, -0.0577145`}, {0.1`, -0.112325`}, {0.15`, \
-0.163893`}, {0.2`, -0.212483`}, {0.25`, -0.258162`}, {0.3`, \
-0.301001`}, {0.35`, -0.341072`}, {0.4`, -0.378448`}, {0.45`, \
-0.413206`}, {0.5`, -0.445422`}, {0.55`, -0.475176`}, {0.6`, \
-0.502545`}, {0.65`, -0.52761`}, {0.7`, -0.550452`}, {0.75`, \
-0.57115`}, {0.8`, -0.589785`}, {0.85`, -0.606438`}, {0.9`, \
-0.621188`}, {0.95`, -0.634114`}, {1, -0.645296`}, {1.05`, \
-0.654811`}, {1.1`, -0.662736`}, {1.15`, -0.669147`}, {1.2`, \
-0.674118`}, {1.25`, -0.677724`}, {1.3`, -0.680035`}, {1.35`, \
-0.681122`}, {1.4`, -0.681054`}, {1.45`, -0.679899`}, {1.5`, \
-0.677722`}, {1.55`, -0.674586`}, {1.6`, -0.670553`}, {1.65`, \
-0.665685`}, {1.7`, -0.660038`}, {1.75`, -0.65367`}, {1.8`, \
-0.646636`}, {1.85`, -0.638987`}, {1.9`, -0.630775`}, {1.95`, \
-0.622048`}, {2, -0.612853`}, {2.05`, -0.603236`}, {2.1`, \
-0.593239`}, {2.15`, -0.582904`}, {2.2`, -0.57227`}, {2.25`, \
-0.561374`}, {2.3`, -0.550254`}, {2.35`, -0.538942`}, {2.4`, \
-0.527471`}, {2.45`, -0.515871`}, {2.5`, -0.504172`}, {2.55`, \
-0.492401`}, {2.6`, -0.480584`}, {2.65`, -0.468745`}, {2.7`, \
-0.456906`}, {2.75`, -0.445089`}, {2.8`, -0.433314`}, {2.85`, \
-0.421599`}, {2.9`, -0.409962`}, {2.95`, -0.398418`}, {3, \
-0.386983`}, {3.05`, -0.375669`}, {3.1`, -0.36449`}, {3.15`, \
-0.353456`}, {3.2`, -0.342578`}, {3.25`, -0.331866`}, {3.3`, \
-0.321327`}, {3.35`, -0.310969`}, {3.4`, -0.300799`}, {3.45`, \
-0.290822`}, {3.5`, -0.281044`}, {3.55`, -0.271468`}, {3.6`, \
-0.2621`}, {3.65`, -0.25294`}, {3.7`, -0.243992`}, {3.75`, \
-0.235258`}, {3.8`, -0.226738`}, {3.85`, -0.218434`}, {3.9`, \
-0.210346`}, {3.95`, -0.202472`}, {4, -0.194814`}, {4.05`, \
-0.187369`}, {4.1`, -0.180136`}, {4.15`, -0.173115`}, {4.2`, \
-0.166301`}, {4.25`, -0.159694`}, {4.3`, -0.153291`}, {4.35`, \
-0.147089`}, {4.4`, -0.141085`}, {4.45`, -0.135276`}, {4.5`, \
-0.129659`}, {4.55`, -0.124229`}, {4.6`, -0.118984`}, {4.65`, \
-0.11392`}, {4.7`, -0.109034`}, {4.75`, -0.10432`}, {4.8`, \
-0.0997754`}, {4.85`, -0.0953961`}, {4.9`, -0.0911781`}, {4.95`, \
-0.0871172`}, {5, -0.0832093`}, {5.05`, -0.0794504`}
```

which I would like to modify before I plot it. I would like to have the second value in each entry be divided by the first, i.e.,

```
{0.05`, -0.0577145`}->{{0.05`, -0.0577145`/0.05}}
```

Is there a way of doing that without having to do it manually? I have searched and could not find anything.

Thank you.

Comment: `{#1, #2 / #1}& @@@ DataUfunction` ?

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several alternative ways to get the desired result:

```
result = ReplaceAll[{a_, b_} :> {a, b/a}] @ DataUfunction 

result // Take[#, 10] & // Grid
```

[image]

You can also do:

```
Module[{d = DataUfunction}, d[[All, 2]] /= d[[All, 1]]; d]
```

and

```
Transpose[{##}/{1, #1} & @@ Transpose[DataUfunction]]
```

The last two will be faster for large inputs.

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3, f4, f5]
f1 = Module[{d = #}, d[[All, 2]] /= d[[All, 1]]; d] &;
f2 = Transpose[{##}/{1, #1} & @@ Transpose[#]] &;
f3 = Transpose[{#[[All, 1]], Join @@ (Ratios /@ #)}] &;
f4 = {#1, #2/#1} & @@@ # &; (* MarcoB's suggestion in comments *)
f5 = ReplaceAll[{a_, b_} :> {a, b/a}] ;
functions = {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5};

data = DataUfunction;
Do[t[i] = First[RepeatedTiming[res[i] = functions[[i]][data]]], {i, 5}];
res[1] == res[2] == res[3] == res[4] == res[5]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Grid[Prepend[Item[#, Background -> LightBlue, 
      Alignment -> Center] & /@ {"function", "timing"}]@
  Transpose[{functions, t /@ Range[5]}], 
 Alignment -> {{Left, "."}, Center}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

With `SeedRandom[1]; data = RandomReal[1, {10^6, 2}];` we get

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`Function[{x, y}, {x, y/x}] @@@ DataUfunction` is work, but some times `Table` is also convenient.

But `Table` **doesn't support** syntax such as below is what a pity.

```
Table[{x, y/x}, {{x, y}, DataUfunction}] (* syntax error *) 
Table[{x, y/x}, {x, y} ∈ DataUfunction] (* syntax error *)
```

So we have to use

```
Table[{First[i],Last[i]/First[i]},{i,DataUfunction}]
```

Or

```
Table[{i[[1]],i[[2]]/i[[1]]},{i,DataUfunction}]
```